# Unable to start spring boot in JNLP with Java WebStart

Tags: java, spring-boot, jnlp

**Question edited.** I'm trying to run spring boot app in JNLP but after resolving all security issues I still get this error. It occurs during spring boot initialization at startup. It's related to spring boot lifecycle somehow and protection domain obviously, but I really do not know how to fix it. JAR runs flawlessly when running as standalone app with `java -jar Test.jar`.

**Exception from Java WebStart console:**

```
   Unable to determine code source archive from \\localhost:8080\jnlp\Test.jar
org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.createArchive(Launcher.java:151)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.<init>(PropertiesLauncher.java:149)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:607)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**The exception occurs in `Launcher.java` (spring-boot-tools):**

```
protected final Archive createArchive() throws Exception {
        ProtectionDomain protectionDomain = getClass().getProtectionDomain();
        CodeSource codeSource = protectionDomain.getCodeSource();
        URI location = (codeSource == null ? null : codeSource.getLocation().toURI());
        String path = (location == null ? null : location.getSchemeSpecificPart());
        if (path == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to determine code source archive");
        }
        File root = new File(path);
        if (!root.exists()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Unable to determine code source archive from " + root);
        }
        return (root.isDirectory() ? new ExplodedArchive(root)
                : new JarFileArchive(root));
    }
```

Spring boot is not able to get the absolute path for the executed spring boot jar - it passes just the URI in a format, in my case \localhost:8080\jnlp\Test.jar, normally the `location` points to the absolute URI of the file. Therefore, spring boot is not able to initialize in Java WebStart.

**My JNLP:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/" href="Test.jnlp">
    <information>

        <vendor>TEST</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://localhost:8080/" />
        <description>Testing Testing</description>
    </information>
    <update check="timeout" policy="always"/>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.8+" />
        <jar href="/jnlp/Test.jar" />
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher" />
</jnlp>
```

Any hints how to push the absolute file path in `Launcher.java` without fixing spring boot library?

**UPDATE:** I see that this could not be very easily resolved... Spring boot simply does not support running from non-file (or non-servlet) locations, as it works with custom classloader. Additionally the `path` variable should be the same as the executed jar, so it is not possible to point boot to the newly downloaded file (the same jar actually). :(

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No. It is not supported and no reply from spring developers.

Comment: So spring boot does not support jnlp?

Comment: My previous reply says it all.

Comment: Any news about this? I ended up in the same situation... :(
Is still unsuported?

Answer (score 0):

[The solution was to add the MODULE layout for the plugin in the pom.xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43127732/7739273)

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <layout>MODULE</layout>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```