# Kotlin Multi-module Project Dependency is Unresolved in test Lifecycle

Tags: maven, testing, kotlin, multi-module

**Project structure:**
Pure Kotlin as multi module maven application

kotlinspringboot (root-module)

- api
- integration-tests

**Problem:**
When I run

```
$ cd ./kotlingspringboot/integration-tests/
$ mvn test
```

or

```
$ cd ./kotlingspringboot/integration-tests/
$ mvn kotlin:test-compile
```

I get following compilation error regarding unresolved reference for a class from *api* module :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.2.21:test-compile (test-compile) on project hello-integration-tests: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] C:\workspace\kotlinspringboot\integration-tests\src\test\kotlin\org\ildar\hello\integration\HelloEndpointTests.kt:[6,18] Unresolved reference: SpringKotlinHelloWorldApplication
```

Note: I've ran previously mvn clean install and verified that .m2 cache  contains valid api module jar.

api (sub-module) pom.xml

```
    ....
    <parent>
        <artifactId>kotlin-spring-boot</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.ildar</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>hello-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
  ....
```

integration-tests (sub-module) pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>kotlin-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.ildar</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>hello-integration-tests</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <goals> <goal>compile</goal> </goals>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <goals> <goal>test-compile</goal> </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Link to a project on github : 
https://github.com/IldarGalikov/kotlinspringboot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Spring removed the "MODULE" Layout in Spring Boot 2.0, maven was complaining about a non existent LayoutType ENUM when trying [Christophs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8362098/christoph-b%c3%b6hme) answer.

Looking at the Docs though helped me resolve the issue: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/repackage-classifier.html

Specifically adding this to the spring-boot-maven-plugin:

```
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>repackage</id>
    <configuration>
      <classifier>exec</classifier>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
</executions>
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is caused by Spring Boot's repackaging of the API jar. It moves the class files of your application from the root of the jar into a BOOT-INF/classes folder in the jar. When compiling the integration tests the kotlin compiler only search the root of the jar for class files and does not look into the BOOT-INF folder. As a result it cannot resolve references to the classes in the API jar.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43127732/8362098) by [Damien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11612/damien) describes how to make Spring Boot keeping your application classes in the root of the jar. If I add the configuration mentioned there to your api/pom.xml the integration tests in your project compile as expected:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <layout>MODULE</layout>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: For me doesn't work. I get this error
cannot convert 'MODULE' to Enum