# Exception when using Spring Boot and Java Web Start (JNLP)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-web-start, jnlp

I'm building an application with Spring Boot. I packaged it as an executable jar. I'd like to deploy this app using Java Web Start. I wrote a JNLP file, but when I'm trying to run it, I get he following Exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to determine code source archive from \\localhost\printpoc.jar
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.createArchive(Launcher.java:126)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.<init>(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:38)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.<init>(JarLauncher.java:35)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my JNLP file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost/" href="printpoc.jnlp">
<information>
    <vendor>Me</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://localhost/" />
    <description>PrintPoc</description>
</information>
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.8+" />
    <jar href="printpoc.jar" />
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher" />
```

I wanted to try [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124852/spring-boot-maven-plugin-no-boot-inf-directory/43127732#43127732), but the layout MODULE doesn't existe anymore. I tried with ZIP, NONE etc, still no success.
Here is my pom.xml :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <layout>JAR</layout>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Coud you please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to me like a Spring bug.  From the [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/loader/Launcher.java#L116):

```
ProtectionDomain protectionDomain = getClass().getProtectionDomain();
CodeSource codeSource = protectionDomain.getCodeSource();
URI location = (codeSource != null) ? codeSource.getLocation().toURI() : null;
String path = (location != null) ? location.getSchemeSpecificPart() : null;

if (path == null) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to determine code source archive");
}

File root = new File(path);
if (!root.exists()) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(
            "Unable to determine code source archive from " + root);
}
```

The problem is this line:

```
String path = (location != null) ? location.getSchemeSpecificPart() : null;
```

From the [URI documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/URI.html):

> At the highest level a URI reference (hereinafter simply "URI") in string form has the syntax
>
> [*scheme*`:`]*scheme-specific-part*[`#`*fragment*]

So, in the URI `http://localhost/printpoc.jnlp`, the scheme-specific part is `//localhost/printpoc.jnlp`.  Spring then tries to treat that as a file name, which of course does not exist, which is why you are seeing the exception you’re seeing.

The Spring code is incorrect.  It wrongly assumes you can make a file name out of any URI.  Only `file:` URIs can be safely converted to file names, and that is correctly done with [new File(location)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/File.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.net.URI)) or [Paths.get(location)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get(java.net.URI)).

I’m not sure what the solution is.  It appears the Spring Boot launcher is assuming the .jar is always a local file.  I doubt it can work with a .jar file obtained via HTTP.

Comment: So I guess reproducing the bahavior of the MODULE layout with a custom LayoutFactory wouldn't work either. What about creating a Jar which contains my Spring boot jar ? The first one would be downloaded and extracted via Java Web Start, then the second one (the spring boot one) would be launched. Does it sound like a doable thing ?

Comment: That might work.  Your Web Start program would probably want to do something like `Path jar = Files.createTempFile(null, ".jar"); try (InputStream embeddedJar = getClass().getResourceAsStream("springboot.jar")) { Files.copy(embeddedJar, jar, REPLACE_EXISTING); }`.